# Copy constructor chosen over move constructor when another constructor is introduced

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, move-semantics

I am struggling with some weird behaviour that I do not understand. Below I have a minimal testcase that reproduces my problem. X is a class that has move semantics. In the code below, I expect that `X<false> f(std::move(t));` results in a call to the templated move constructor. However, this results in a call to the templated copy constructor. Except when I remove the third templated constructor, then everything works as expected:

```
template<bool C>
class X
{
public:
    X() {}
    X(const X& other) {}
    X(X&& other) {}

    template<bool C2>
        X(const X<C2>& other) {}  // This constructor is actually being called
    template<bool C2>
        X(X<C2>&& other) {}  // I expected this constructor to be called

    template<class F>
        X(F f) {}      // If this constructor is removed, the expected constructor is called, removing my confusion
};

void testX()
{
    X<true> t;
    X<false> f(std::move(t));
}
```

Is there a good reason why the `const X<C2>& other` variant is picked over `X<C2>&& other`, or is this a bug in Visual Studio 2013?
If this is a bug, are there any ideas for working around this problem (other than removing the last templated constructor)?

Comment: Behaves as you expect with gcc 4.8.2, clang 3.3

Comment: clang is good too, in regards to c++11 conformance test of Visual studio, always test things with clang first. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe3b97c577cdb8c1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have submitted a bug report for Visual Studio 2013 at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/814740/copy-constructor-chosen-over-move-constructor-when-another-constructor-is-introduced#

A workaround was reported there:
Move the template X(F f) constructor above the other templated constructors, and then the correct move constructor is called.